# Не получается нажать кнопку ОК в окне приложения

Tags: c#, winapi

Написал программу, которая запускает установленное на ПК приложение, и проверяет, появилась ли окно об ошибке при запуске, или нет.
Использую функции WinApi. Приложение запускается, моя программа находит его, находит окно с сообщением об ошибке, но не получается нажать на кнопку ОК в этом окне.

Переменная `loginPromptOKButtonHWND` всегда равна нулю, и поэтому, не могу нажать на кнопку ОК. Почему это и как это исправить?

```
loginPromptOKButtonHWND = FindWindowEx(loginPromptHWND, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK"); 
SendMessage(loginPromptHWND, WM_COMMAND, BN_CLICKED, loginPromptOKButtonHWND);
```

`loginPromptHWND` - содержит идентификатор окна с ошибкой. работает правильно, окно находится.

"Button" - название класса объекта в окне, проверил в Spy++ - все верно

Comment: А что мешает просто послать окну WM_OK?

Answer (score 2):

Так должно работать

```
loginPromptOKButtonHWND = FindWindowEx(loginPromptHWND, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
SendMessage(loginPromptOKButtonHWND, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```